# How to stop the iPython notebook to run the command line, run only python code

Tags: python, terminal, ipython

I am using iPython notebook build a online interactive teaching website, but I don't want users to run command line, any idea how to remove iPython notebook command line function? Is there any configuration or something? I have been stuck here for 3 days!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make `os.system` or `subprocess` unavailable, and users could use these to build themselves terminals even if you disable the built in terminals. However, if you run the ipython instance in a sandbox then it won't matter that they have command line access.

Comment: I have seen others successfully disabling `os.system` and `command line function`, also I have tried using docker as a sandbox, but I am considering a better solution, sandbox may used up too much machine resources.

Comment: I would like to see the same feature - it is not because of security - it is because of extremely easy access to everything.  Doing it in python 1/ you need to know a bit;  2/ you dont do a random mistake so easily...